# login program not working, whatever input

Tags: python, python-3.x

Program to **login in**, using a **file** called *'UserAccounts.txt'*

```
def login():
    print("logging in, ok")
    counter = 0
    while counter <= 5:
         Username = input("Username:")
         Password = input("Password:")
         users = open("UserAccounts.txt","r")
         entry = False
     ########### v checks file v #############
         for record in users:
             if record == Username:
                 Pass = record
                 if Pass == Password:
                     print("logged in")
                     entry = True
         if entry == False:
             print("Incorret, try again")
             counter = counter + 1


     print("LOCKED: Tried over 5 times")
```

Code always outputting no matter input:

```
logging in, ok
Username:El
Password:Password
Incorret, try again
Username:
```

Do you know why? (when user and password are in file)

Thank you for helping, have a good day!
(probably simple problem but brain isn't working)

Comment: What is the structure of the file?

Comment: Can you provide the first line of `UserAccounts.txt`? looks like you're reading the text file incorrectly.

Comment: You're setting `Pass = record` right before you check whether or not `Pass == Password`, which is unlikely to occur. I suspect you mean `record.next()` or something along those lines.

Comment: Simon,34,Secure,123.45.6.78 @RickyKim

Comment: Also, you will have newlines `\n` at the end of `record` while you iterate on the lines.

Answer (score 0):

When reading line by line, the line is seperated by comma, so you need to split by commas before declaring them as `Username` or `Pass`.

```
def login():
    print("logging in, ok")
    counter = 0
    while counter <= 5:
        Username = input("Username:")
        Password = input("Password:")
        users = open("UserAccounts.txt","r")
        entry = False
    ########### v checks file v #############
        for record in users:
            if record.split(',')[0] == Username:
                Pass = record.split(',')[1] #assuming 34 is pwd. [2] if 'Secure' is the pwd
                if Pass == Password:
                    print("logged in")
                    entry = True #maybe replace this line with "return" to stop while loop
        if entry == False:
            print("Incorret, try again")
            counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: logging in, ok
Username:Simon
Password:34
Username:Simon
Password:34
Username: - returns this every time

Comment: @Theo It's because you never exit out of while loop if you log in successfully. That's why I put a comment on that line that you should probably put `return` instead of `entry=True` to exit out of the loop

Comment: after the change I said, running `login()` function outputs: logging in, ok
Username:Simon
Password:34
logged in

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: looks like login method works? why do you say semi working?

Comment: if your inputs are incorrect it will return: logging in, ok
Username:a
Password:s
Incorret, try again
Incorret, try again
Incorret, try again
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 76, in <module>
    login()
  File "main.py", line 59, in login
    if record.split(',')[1] == Username:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Theo I don't get the same error as you from running the above code. From running above, it just asks 5 times and finishes. It's probably other part of your code that is causing the issue.